# Why doesn't button state remain?

Tags: swift2

I have the following code:

```
@IBAction func mybuttonclick(sender: UIButton) {
    if(sender.titleLabel?.text == "Start"){
        sender.titleLabel?.text = "Change"
    }
    else {
        sender.titleLabel?.text = "Start"
    }
}
```

When I click the button, I see "Change" flash and then it goes back to "Start".  This is a simple new test app.  The above is the only code I have in the app.  Why does the button text change back to "Start" instead of remaining on "Change"?

Answer (score 0):

Its very hard to answer this question without more information, but I think it's possible you have the action bound twice in Interface Builder.  Where the action is being fired twice each time you hit the button.  Another possibility is you have the button inside a table or collection view cell where the cell is being reused and replacing your previously edited button.